# Как лучше всего работать с сервером на JS через Rest API?

Tags: javascript, rest

Как лучше всего работать с сервером на JS через Rest API?Какую библиотеку лучше всего использовать?Слышал про fetch и XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: И оба варианта не библиотеки. Fetch не поддерживается всякими эксплорерами. xhttp не такой удобный без абстракции например с промисами поверх него. Библиотек вагон, начиная от jQuery и заканчивая axios, и внезапно requests

Comment: [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) конечно :) На промисах построена. С async/await работать можно. Удобная, в общем. И ие11 норм поддерживается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` - довольно старый, но при этом быстрый метод. Проблема его заключается в том, что нужно сначала написать обертку над ним, чтобы было удобно пользоваться, иначе получается очень много коду, который будет дублироваться.

`fetch` - новый метод для выполнения запросов. Реализует интерфейс Promise, и с ним удобно работать. Проблема в том, что он еще не поддерживается многими браузерами.

Отличным выбором может стать библиотека `axios`. Она легкая и реализует интерфейс Promise.

Так же хорошим вариантом может быть `whatwg-fetch`. По сути это просто полифил для `fetch`. Она отлично подойдет тем, кто планирует поддерживать проект долгое время. И как только `fetch` будет хорошо поддерживаться браузерами - эту библиотеку можно будет удалить, а код останется работать без изменений, используя при этом нативный `fetch`.